# Generic term for "objects" vs "fundamental types"?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, design, floating-point

What are the exact terms to call **data types with a logic structure** (like C structures, C++ or Java objects) versus **fundamental data types** (like numeric types, characters, booleans...) independently of any language or paradigm. (I am searching for abstract/academic computer science words).

Comment: structs/objects are normally called Cartesian Products.

Comment: @tp1 Only among people who take one (admittedly insightful) idea from type theory too far. Almost everyone else will stare at you blankly, even/especially those who are familiar with the more common use of "Cartesian product".

Comment: Numeric types, characters and booleans are called [primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: @delnan: Structs / records were introduced to me as Cartesian products in my first semester at college.

Comment: @Giorgio It's entirely possible that your professors fall under the characterization I gave six months ago.

Comment: @delnan: Well, this approach is quite standard in the country where I come from, so very few who have taken an usual Computer Science degree there would stare at you blankly if you described records as Cartesian products. But it is entirely possible that in other countries they follow a different approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Object-Oriented systems they are almost universally called "Objects" and "Primitive Types" respectively.  Before we had OO, there were "Data Structures" and "Primitive Types".

Answer (score 2):

I would say **compound data-types**. As an example, see those documentations for different languages: [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/), [guile](http://www.lonelycactus.com/guilebook/charrays.html) and [C (beware, audio speech)](http://www.tud.ttu.ee/im/Vladimir.Viies/kaugope/materjalikogu_0tase/ThinkingInC-Beta3/Chapters/chap5/Lecture.html).

Also, check [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Compound_data_type), where the term is defined as:

```
[a type] that holds multiple independent values.
```

This definition encompasses arrays, structures, classes, and so on.
Here, "value" means either a primitive type or another compound type, I guess.

Comment: +1 _compound data type_ is more general than _object_, _structure_ or _record_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any.

It depends entirely on the language: in Lambda Calculus, functions (and *only* functions) are primitive, booleans, numbers, strings, lists are not. In Smalltalk, objects are primitive, integers are not. In C, integers are primitive, objects are not. Pairs are not primitive in Java, but they are in Scheme. Java makes a difference between primitives and objects, C# doesn't.

Comment: Please fix this "booleans are primitive" heretic statement before the ayatollahs of the Cee language have a chance to see your post!

Comment: ARRRRGH, the One Holy Standard of the Language C says nothing about your evil booleans!

Comment: I replaced "boolean" with "integer".

Answer (score -2):

<strike>#Abstract Data Types</strike>

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type):

> In computer science, an abstract data type (ADT) is a mathematical
>   model for a certain class of data structures that have similar
>   behavior; or for certain data types of one or more programming
>   languages that have similar semantics. An abstract data type is
>   defined indirectly, only by the operations that may be performed on it
>   and by mathematical constraints on the effects (and possibly cost) of
>   those operations.

(or just say "data structure", most people will know what you mean)

Exact academic terms are arguable (see comments); I say 'data structure' or even 'abstract data type' and have no trouble being understood. 'Object' is more specific than what you asked for.

If you want total precision, say 'primitive' and 'non-primitive' (or 'secondary').

I'm wondering why this matters? What's the purpose?

Comment: So you would say "Abstract Data Types" vs "Primitive Types" ?

Comment: @Vincent: I would, yes. Not sure if there is an 'official' answer though. To me, an ADT is a structure, but the formal definition references 'access through behaviors'. You could also say 'data structure' and most people will know what you mean.

Comment: The OP mentioned "objects", however, which are fundamentally different from ADTs. See [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited* by William R. Cook](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) for details.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: very interesting, thanks for the reference. The author (Cook) says "Academic computer science has generally not accepted the fact that there is another form of data abstraction besides abstract data types" but then later says "When classes are used as types, the programmer is implicitly choosing to use a form of abstract data type". Professor Cook is trying to make a very precise distinction here which may or may not be a generally accepted definition; I don't know. Answer revised to err on the side of caution ;)